# Snowflake SQL: concat values from multiple rows based on shared key

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table of values where there are a variable number of rows per each key value.  I want to output a table that concats those row values together onto each distinct key value.

INPUT TABLE

| KEY_ID | SOURCE_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | e |
| 3 | f |

Target OUTPUT TABLE

| KEY_ID | OUTPUT_VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c |
| 2 | d |
| 3 | e,f |

What is the most efficient way to write this in Snowflake SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It could be done with [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html):

```
SELECT KEY_ID, 
       LISTAGG(SOURCE_VAL, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SOURCE_VAL) AS OUTPUT_VAL
FROM tab
GROUP BY KEY_ID
```