# Snowflake: how to form a string from an ARRAY with OBJECT types inside?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column `TAGS` of type `ARRAY` in table `ITEM` that looks like this:

| TAGS |
| --- |
| [{"Name": 'Alice', "Department": 'Sales', "ID": 123}, {"Name": 'Bob', "Department": 'HR', "ID": 456}] |
| [{"Name": 'Charles', "Department": 'Director', "ID": 789}] |

As you can see, the number of elements inside the `ARRAY` does not match. What I want is to construct a string for each row, that gets only the `Name` and `ID` of all elements, separated by the character `,`. This is the desired result:

| TAGS |
| --- |
| 'Alice: 123, Bob: 456' |
| 'Charles: 789' |

How can I do that in Snowflake? Ideally, I would like to use it in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Did you try flattening it? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Comment: I tried it but it gives me one row for each element, which is not what I want. In the desired output above, Alice and Bob stay in the same row.

Comment: Could you please add some DDL to create your sample data?

Comment: @Rajat I figured out the answer. Thanks for your help in pointing to Lateral Flatten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to figure this out. The trick is to use a combination of `LATERAL FLATTEN` and `LISTAGG`. A requirement is the table must have an ID associated with a row (which can be easily generated):

| ID | TAGS |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"Name": 'Alice', "Department": 'Sales', "ID": 123}, {"Name": 'Bob', "Department": 'HR', "ID": 456}] |
| 2 | [{"Name": 'Charles', "Department": 'Director', "ID": 789}] |

Then we can use:

```sql
select list_agg(value:"Name"::varchar || ': ' || value:"ID"::varchar, ', ')
from ITEM,
lateral flatten(input => ITEM.TAGS)
group by ID;
```

Comment: For further information, after LATERAL FLATTEN, it is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974553/snowflake-sql-concat-values-from-multiple-rows-based-on-shared-key)